# Can i force webcomponents.js to re-parse the DOM on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Well, i need it to re-parse at a specific time.

Why?

I dynamically add a component and it doesn't get "polyfilled" if you know what i mean. stays like this:

```
<div id="componente" allowfullscreen=""><viva-card1></viva-card1></div>
```

but viva-card DOES have stuff and a prototype etc, etc. it just doesn't show up on firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can force `webcomponents.js` to synchronously upgrade elements:

`WebComponents.upgradeAll(document.querySelector('#componente'));`

This will synchronously upgrade the entire tree, starting with #componente (if it's a component).

For more information, see [webcomponentsjs/issues/#169](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/169).

Comment: thanks, though i'm not using polymer anymore, due to some time sensitivity the work got and polymer wasn't ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's inside the viva-card1 so here are some general rules I learned by using Polymer almost full time for the last 3 months.

If you do it outside of a Polymer element, it works perfectly fine by using

```
someElement.innerHTML = 'HTML content goes here';
```

Or

```
var newDomElement = document.createElement('viva-card1');
someElement.appendChild(newDomElement);
```

If you inject html inside a Polymer element, use this in the "javascript part of the element":

```
this.injectBoundHTML(html, elementId);
```

If you include your own CSS along with it:

```
<link id="someCSS" href="something.css" shim-shadowdom>
```

You can do this using

```
document.getElementById('someCSS').setAttribute('shim-shadowdom', '');
```

If you need to dynamically include a CSS file using AJAX after page load using javascript, just setting shim-shadowdom doesn't work however and you need to use this (using jQuery ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'link_to_css',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        var css = Platform.ShadowCSS.shimCssText(data);
        Platform.ShadowCSS.addCssToDocument(css);
    }
});
```

If you need to shim inline CSS, like

```
<style id="the_css">
  html /deep/ div { margin: 0}
</style>
```

You need to assign an ID to the inline CSS and do this (using jQuery in the first line):

```
var data = $('#the_css').text();
var css = Platform.ShadowCSS.shimCssText(data);
Platform.ShadowCSS.addCssToDocument(css);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it might help in someway, but i found what i was looking for: Platform.flush() as mentioned in my own answer. :)

Comment: Though helpful, this answer relates to Polymer, not webcomponents.js itself. Polymer consumes webcomponents.js, but they are separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. you should call `Platform.flush()`

Bear in mind that you should only do that if it is REALLY needed as described on [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#flush)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some kind of lazy loading, you could use Polymer.import

```
// Signature: Polymer.import(urls, callback)
Polymer.import( ['polymer-cat.html'], function() {
  // called when our import is fully loaded
  // including any assets like CSS.
});
```

This loads import dynamically and asynchronously. The callback is called when the imports have loaded and any associated polymer-elements have upgraded.

Comment: I was actually using it and it was one of the problems. not sure why in FF it wouldn't register them properly. My solution was document.head.innerHTML += importArray[x]; thank you anyways.